# Convert text of numbers to date and time

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

the output I get for date and time from my database is like this: 20181003134521. The format is yyyymmddhhmmss.  This would be in actuality 10/03/2018 13:45:21. What formula in Excel can I use to convert the former into the latter? And it has to be in a 24hr clock.

Answer (score 3):

While Scott's answer works fine in Excel, I found it doesn't work in LibreOffice Calc, where the formula with `--` gives an error and without it creates a text string.

I offer an alternative which works on both:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))+TIME(MID(A1,9,2),MID(A1,11,2),MID(A1,13,2))
```

The result is a date and time field stored numerically.

I tested this and it works whether the source `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` field (`A1`) is stored as text or numeric data: the latter works because of implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula to add the necessary characters to allow Excel to convert it to a date/time:

```
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,13,0,":"),11,0,":"),9,0," "),7,0,"/"),5,0,"/")
```

Then format the cell:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

[image]